# Application seems to be hanging on SocketRead

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

We're migrating an application from Java 6 to Java 7.  At the high level, the issue is that its slower.

Going into more detail, we've been upgrading classes as the profiler tells us hot spots.  At this point we have `java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)` showing up with 42% of the usage when using `jvisualvm`'s sampler.

Doing a thread dump, many of the threads have this stack

```
"RMI TCP Connection(68)-192.168.1.198" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff3279f3800 nid=0x49d2b runnable [0x000000013e279000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    - locked <0x00000007f881b7f0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:538)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x0000000763e82c50> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

My understanding of this is that the application is hanging on a response.  I can't tell if its a response from the database or from our testing endpoint.  We mimic http requests and shoot them at our application in our testing.

Googling around I've tried setting the following properties:

`-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout=5000`

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

with no effect.

Here is a quick rundown of what could be relevant in our setup

- Centos or Mac (both have issue)
- mysql 5.1.73
- c3po
- hibernate 4.3.6

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the context of this socket communication is, but most likely the numbers you are seeing are not really a problem...

- If the thread is constantly connected to a socket, reading data when available and processing it, then it is normal to see a high usage for socketRead0. It just means that 42% of the time no data is available for processing, so socketRead0 blocks waiting for data (thus 42% of the time the thread is alive is being spent inside the socketRead0 method). In fact in this case, I would recomment splitting processing data and reading data into two separate threads (which would make the reading thread report even high usage percentage in socketRead0).
- If socketRead0 is the result of ad-hoc "queries" (that is, your code is requesting data regularly over a socket connection), then the 42% is just the amount of time these requests for data are taking (which  includes the time the remote process takes to generate the data and the time to read the data over the network). If this time is too much, you need to look at speeding up the other end of the socket, or the throughput and/or latency to it).